# Can i read interval value from another column in database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with `(custid,purchase_timestamp (dd-mm-yyyy), warranty_period)` in days. I need the sum of purchase_time and warranty_period.How can i write SQL for this.

I tried

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(purchase_timestamp, INTERVAL warranty_period DAY);
```

but it does not work. Please suggest

```
 |custid |    warranty_period  |   purchase_timestamp
    |1        |      365            |   03-01-2017  
    |2        |      30             |   03-04-2017
    |3        |     10              |   25-05-2017
    |4        |      30             |   20-05-2017
    |5        |     365             |   04-06-2017
    |6        |     100             |   18-06-2017
    |7        |     90              |   30-06-2017
    |8        |     10              |   05-07-2017
    |9        |        30           |   09-07-2017
    |10       |     365             |   17-07-2017
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? The functions for date manipulation and formatting are different in both databases. It isn't likely that there is a statement that runs on *both* databases.

Comment: PostgreSQL. Running this query on redshift DB

Comment: There is no `date_sub()` in Postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume this is your table:

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    custid integer,
    warranty_period integer,
    purchase_timestamp date /* timestamp ? */
);
```

with this data:

```
INSERT INTO t
    (custid, warranty_period, purchase_timestamp)
VALUES
    ( 1, 365, '03-01-2017'),  
    ( 2,  30, '03-04-2017'),
    ( 3,  10, '25-05-2017'),
    ( 4,  30, '20-05-2017'),
    ( 5, 365, '04-06-2017'),
    ( 6, 100, '18-06-2017'),
    ( 7,  90, '30-06-2017'),
    ( 8,  10, '05-07-2017'),
    ( 9,  30, '09-07-2017'),
    (10, 365, '17-07-2017') ;
```

You can just use the following `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    custid,
    purchase_timestamp + cast(warranty_period || ' days' AS interval) AS end_of_warranty 
FROM
    t 
ORDER BY
    custid ;
```

or

```
SELECT 
    custid,
    purchase_timestamp + make_interval(days := warranty_period) AS end_of_warranty 
FROM
    t 
ORDER BY
    custid ;
```

and get

```
custid | end_of_warranty    
-----: | :------------------
     1 | 2018-01-03 00:00:00
     2 | 2017-05-03 00:00:00
     3 | 2017-06-04 00:00:00
     4 | 2017-06-19 00:00:00
     5 | 2018-06-04 00:00:00
     6 | 2017-09-26 00:00:00
     7 | 2017-09-28 00:00:00
     8 | 2017-07-15 00:00:00
     9 | 2017-08-08 00:00:00
    10 | 2018-07-17 00:00:00
```

Note just that PostgreSQL know how to *add* an interval to a date (or timestamp), and will return a timestamp.

To specify your interval you need to use

```
cast(warranty_period || ' days' AS interval)
```

or

```
warranty_period * interval '1 day'
```

which are close to the SQL standard, or use

```
make_interval(days := warranty_period)
```

that uses a specific [PostgreSQL date/time function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE).

---

You can just also use the (simplest) form:

```
SELECT 
    custid,
    purchase_timestamp + warranty_period AS end_of_warranty 
FROM
    t 
ORDER BY
    custid ;
```

That relies on the fact that there is a `+` operator for (date + integer) that treats the integer as number of *days*, and perform the same operation. In this case, the column `purchase_timestamp` should *actually* be a date, or be `CAST(... AS date)`.

Check out all the options at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=eeebe78ba30bc8785013912c8c1419ac)*

Answer (score 0):

**`SELECT DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE(purchase_timestamp,'%d-%m-%Y'), INTERVAL warranty_period DAY);`**

You can try above code.

Here I had added function [**`STR_TO_DATE`**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php).

Using this function you have to convert your string into **`DATE`**.

Otherwise your **`DATE`** field must in **`'YYYY-MM-DD'`** format.Then only MySQL engine consider your string as date.

You can try above query.

Here is a [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8bbcd/1).

Comment: getting an errorERROR: syntax error at or near "warranty_period" Position

Comment: @PreetiKumar You have to put your table name and then try to execute.

Comment: i am trying with table name.Checked on sqlfiddle - same error.

Comment: Which error??
Did you check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8bbcd/1   ??